# Obtaining clicked element's ID in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My Angular controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('spark')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope,$location) {
        $scope.handleThisElement = function (event) {
            alert(event.target.id);
        }
        $scope.changeView = function(view){
            $location.path(view);
        }
    }]);
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<a id="testID" href="" ng-click="handleThisElement($event); changeView('panel3')">
...
</a>
```

The alert pops up before the application routes to a different view, which is what I want. But when it comes up, the alert box is empty. How can I get it to read the id of the clicked link (i.e. 'testID')?

Comment: are there tags inside the `<a>`? If so those could be the actual target and you would need to traverse to parent

Comment: Ah..... Yes there are. Let me monkey with it for a bit.

Comment: Think you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget typically with angular it's better to be passing through the data element used in the view and modify the model instead of depending on the DOM

Comment: @shaunhusain: Thank you. currentTarget.id worked for me. If you want to suggest it as an answer below I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting as a quick answer you can use event.currentTarget instead of event.target in order to get the element the binding was registered on.  In this case the ng-click binds to the element you apply it to so you should get that element.  As mentioned in the comments this is an atypical way to go as it ties the Controller to the DOM which means the Controller can't be tested or used independent of a particular DOM (breaks testability).