# Using ng-model (or other solution) without breaking MVC paradigm

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854803/obtaining-clicked-elements-id-in-angularjs) on Stack where I was trying to obtain a DOM element's ID via AngularJS' `ng-click`. Essentially the answer which was given (with an important caveat was):

Use `event.currentTarget` vs `event.target` to get the element to which the binding was registered, BUT this is an atypical way to do it because it ties the controller to the DOM when ideally the controller should know nothing about the DOM.

I'm starting to get a better idea of this now, but would like some further help / clarification.

Using `ng-repeat` I dynamically render a number of tiles being pulled from a database and present them to the user for selection. When a user clicks on a given tile I want to be able to 'know' that element's ID (or some unique identifier key) so that I can pass it into my javascript / java and then retrieve the details for said key where they are rendered in a different, more detailed view.

I've started to research `ng-model` which supports the two-way MVC idea, but I'm stuck. You can see below that I'm dynamically rendering each tile with a different `ng-model` value which equals the tile's database key. Is this the solution I want? If so, how can I reference the `ng-model` value in javascript? Or if I do that, am I breaking the MVC again? If that's the case, what would be a solution which preserves the model?

Cheers

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in tileResult">
    <div ng-model={{tile.id}} ng-click="handleThisElement($event); changeView('panel3')" class="container-fluid btn-default tile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="row">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 tile-stats">
                <div class="row text-center">
                ...             
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no, you don't want to do it that way. you want to link the model to an object (string) on the $scope not via {{ }} templating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tie the ng-model to an object, best if it's something in the repeater. Also, ng-model is generally used with an input... not on a div, so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

You may want to initialize the value to the index (or some other default) if the value doesn't exist, this will avoid null pointers when you want to change the value later.

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in tileResult">
    <div ng-model="tile.someDataValue" ng-init="tile.someDataValue = $index" ng-click="handleThisElement($event); changeView('panel3')" class="container-fluid btn-default tile">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

To later reference the value, you can just access your tileResult object at the appropriate value/index
Ex:

```
console.log($scope.tileResult[0].someDataValue);
```

Or you can access the entire 'tile' on click by passing the 'tile' into a function. Ex:

```
<div ng-model="tile.someDataValue" ng-init="tile.someDataValue = $index" ng-click="someFunction(tile); handleThisElement($event); changeView('panel3')" class="container-fluid btn-default tile">

$scope.someFunction = function(someTile){
   console.log(someTile.id, someTile); // log the id, then the entire object
}
```

Comment: as @BradenEricson mentions, you don't need ng-model, it's used with input fields for two way binding... the id can be accessed different ways, you should elaborate on what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Still reading the rest, but before I get too far, I did see from my research that using `ng-model` with a div is not the norm. Is there a better way to go about it (not using `ng-model`) and still passing the key value of a clicked element underneath the `ng-repeat` without breaking MVC?

Comment: how does that break MVC? I'm unclear. You can pass the key in the function, or you can pass the entire object in the click function and read the key.

Comment: I was told it breaks it because the controller directly references the DOM. Maybe this is not correct? See original link in my post - it points to the question I asked yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to access the unique identifier for each tile.

This can easily be done without Ng-Model! One easy fix would be to set the id of each element with the unique identifier:

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in tileResult">
<div id="{{tile.id}}" ng-click="handleThisElement($event); changeView('panel3')" class="container-fluid btn-default tile">
    <div class="row">
```

This way, when you pass *$event* to your *handleThisElement* function, you are able to access the id in the same way you have before.

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing, but it breaks the MVC paradigm.

Comment: I don't see how this breaks MVC paradigm. Your controller contains the data. Your view displays the data. On click, your controller determines which element was clicked and can fire handleThisElement. Elaborate where the MVC paradigm is broken?

Comment: This would not break the MVC pattern. see here (the definition of model): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Your ids are not models because their values are static.

Comment: I'm a little confused. In the original question I posted the other day, I was told that it would break it because the controller is directly referencing an element of the DOM through `event.currentTarget` ? Maybe I was misinformed? Please see my original link.

Comment: @EliteOctagon: I included it in OP above. Under 'question': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854803/obtaining-clicked-elements-id-in-angularjs

Comment: referencing the element of the DOM that way is a general practice in JS. You should post that as a question of it's own and look at what front-end developers tell you. Again, you don't need to reference it via event.currentTarget. You can just pass the data in the repeater.

Comment: Yes. It was working fine in JS. I'm just trying to get a feel for the Angular method and understand why it is the way it is. My big question, does the JS solution from my prior question break the MVC? And still wrapping my head around your above answer....

Comment: After reading the answer, the focus to me seems to be on testing. Angular ties the controller to the DOM by itself... that's kinda the point in angular. It depends what your function is doing, once again, you don't need to use $event to get the data... it really depends on what the function is doing. It might be more "MVC" to pass the object from ng-repeat rather than to use $event. Either way you won't be testing the function on the DOM, your jasmine/karma tests will require you to set up the test first to see that the function works.